# datepicker in pop window not working

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datepicker

Below code is in popup window...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({


changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 yearRange: "-100:+0",
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
 });
  </script>
```

This is my view code

```
<li><?php
                        echo anchor_popup(base_url()."index.php/controller_bookaplot", "Book Plot", $atts = array(
                            'width' => '800',
                            'height' => '600',
                            'scrollbars' => 'yes',
                            'status' => 'yes',
                            'resizable' => 'yes',
                            'screenx' => '0',
                            'screeny' => '0'
                        ));
                        ?></li>
```

and in controller_bookplot i m loading view called bookplot_new. But in that popup window datepicker is not showing. Same code is working with normal window..so anybody tell me about this...i have included all the jquery needed for this. how to solve this problem...

Comment: Since you are telling when you are opening the popup page in normal browser, it works, Just check if you have any javascript errors in the console

Comment: it's not working with popup window..and works with normal window.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $(document).live(function()
   {

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({


changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 yearRange: "-100:+0",
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
 });
```